# Rails 5: Kaminari gem with ajax setup

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, kaminari

I have already installed the `kaminari gem` and it's working fine with my `rails 5` app. On a page where I have the comments I'm trying to implement the pagination via `Ajax` and thus without refreshing the page. The comments are located inside panel with tabs.

This is the setup I have thus far:

`gem 'kaminari'`

the controller action

```
 def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js  { render 'show.js.erb' }
    format.html
  end
end
```

show.js.erb

```
$("#pages-comments").html("<%= escape_javascript render(@comments) %>")
$("#paginator").html("<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@comments, remote: true)) %>")
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="comments">
     <div class="pages-comments">
        <%= render 'comments/comment' %>
      </div>

      <div id="paginator">
         <%= paginate @comments, remote: true %>
      </div>

 </div>
```

and even though it seems like the `show.js.erb` file is rendering when I click on the pagination links it doesn't redirect me to the next page. Also I'm not getting no errors inside the browser inspector.

This is what the console when using `byebug` shows:

```
  Rendering pages/show.js.erb
  Comment Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
   (1.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Shopper Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE Shopper Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "shoppers".* FROM "shoppers" WHERE "shoppers"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  CACHE  (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT  1 FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8 ORDER BY "comments"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2) subquery_for_count  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.erb [10 times] (822.0ms)
   (1.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."item_id" = 8
  Rendered pages/show.js.erb (1205.3ms)
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

**Update 1**
After implemnting @Gabbar answer  and when I click on the next page I get this:

```
Started GET "/show/8?page=2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-01 16:51:39 +0200
Processing by PagesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"page"=>"2", "id"=>"8"}
  Item Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)



TypeError (no implicit conversion of Integer into String):

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:33:in `+'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:33:in `show'
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a bedbug in rails. Change it to byebug in your question

Comment: can you check the `params[:page]` value at controller if its getting increment after very ajax request or not, if its not then you need to increment it at controller `params[:page] +1`

Comment: thanks for the reply @Aniket Shivam Tiwari, I just noticed that its a typo I meant `byebug`. I'm really using `byebug`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gabbar. I did this `@item = Item.find(params[:id]) @comments = Comment.where(item_id: @item).order(created_at: :desc).page.params[:page] if params[:page].nil?  redirect_to plans_path, notice:'no params!' end` and when I refreshed the page it did redirect me. Thus, I'm not getting any values for the params[:page]. How exactly can can I increment this in the controller as u said?

Comment: lets try the solution given below, let me know for further guidance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you try this

```
 def show
  params[:page] ||= 1
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  @comments = @item.comments.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
  #if params[:page].class == String
    #params[:page].to_i = params[:page].to_i + 1
  #else
    #params[:page] = params[:page] + 1
  #end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js  { render 'show.js.erb' }
    format.html
  end
end
```

in show.js.erb

```
$(".pages-comments").html("<%= escape_javascript render(@comments) %>"); 
$("#paginator").html("<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@comments, remote: true)) %>");
```

Comment: I"m getting an error in console, please check my question I have update it with the error. Thanks

Comment: `params[:page].to_i += 1.to_i` replace with this of line 33

Comment: @Theopap check the modification in answer and try it

Comment: `undefined method to_i=' for 1:Integer Did you mean? to_i to_int to_f to_d to_s to_r to_c`

Comment: `params[:page].to_i += 1` could you try this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160294/discussion-between-gabbar-and-theopap).